# Strange behavior of mysql query string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm toying around with mysql and PHP and hit a VERY strange problem:

After establishing a successful database connection I set two variables for the query:

```
$searchcolor = $_SESSION["color"];
$searchprice = $_POST["price"];

$query = "SELECT `toys`.`id` FROM `database`.`toys` WHERE `toys`.`color` = $searchcolor AND `toys`.`price` = $searchprice;";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo $query;
```

This querys won't work. When echoing it, it reads the correct string, like:

```
SELECT `toys`.`id` FROM `database`.`toys` WHERE `toys`.`color` = brown AND `toys`.`price` = 1500;
```

This code, however, works just fine:

```
$searchcolor = $_SESSION["color"];
$searchprice = $_POST["price"];

$query = "SELECT `toys`.`id` FROM `database`.`toys` WHERE `toys`.`color` = $searchcolor AND `toys`.`price` = 1500;";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo $query;
```

First I though the `$searchprice` wasn't getting it's content by the `$_POST` array correctly. But the `echo`ed search query in the first example seems to be fine.

It also works when setting `$searchprice = 1500;` instead of getting the `$_POST`-value.

I tried casting it to integer and stuff, but that didn't worked.

Cheers and thanks for every hint on this!

(The code is shortened!)

Table structure of toys:

```
id int(10)
name varchar(10)
color varchar(10)
price int(20)
```

Edit:

Woah, just made an interesting discovery:

```
echo "-".$searchprice."-";
```

Gives -5-

```
if ($searchprice == 5){echo "1";}
if ($searchprice == "5"){echo "2";}
```

Gives.. nothing?!

```
var_dump($searchprice);
```

Gives string(14) "5"

Edit:

```
echo bin2hex($searchprice);
```

Gives 3c6e6f62723e353c2f6e6f62723e (?!)

Solution: I used a unicode character in the submitting form. That broke everything. Lesson: Avoid unicode.

Comment: One thing that would stop those queries from working is that you have a string in the sql for the color which does not have quotes around it.

Comment: Are you supposed to get the 2 variables one from POST and one from SESSION?

Comment: Even with quotes it won't work. The variables are substituted correctly.

Comment: what do you mean with "won't work"? do you have some errors?

Comment: Getting the variables from SESSION and POST is correct.

Comment: use single quotes once as $_POST['price'] and IF that doesn't works then use SESSION for accepting $searchprice value just to check  !

Comment: Single quotes won't work and storing the variable in SESSION didn't the trick either. But thanks for the hint =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should read this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Try this:

```
$q = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT toys.id FROM toys WHERE toys.color = ? AND toys.price = ?');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'si', $searchcolor, $searchprice); //d for double

$searchcolor = $_SESSION['color'];
$searchprice = $_POST['price'];

mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
```

---

Before that you should connect properly with DB. I see that you used `database` in `FROM`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Comment: Even when putting $searchcolor and $searchprice before the preparation it won't work. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Did you try that query manually? There are any results? There is any error maybe?

Comment: Are you getting a DB connection.  This example shows bare bones for setting of parametrized prepared statements, you really hshould capture and handle errors in your real code. This includes when making DB connection.

Comment: Jep, I do have an active connection. When I substitute $searchprice by 1500 in the query string every works just as pleased.

Comment: What `var_dump($_POST['price'])` will show you? Stupid question but - are you 100% sure that you're connecting to good database?

Comment: var dump gives a string. That should be normal since all POST-Variables are strings. Converting it to an integer doesn't seems to work.. mh. The database is good, im sure =)

Comment: Well... Try again my code. Should work without any change. If not working - only reason is that `$_SESSION['color']` AND `$_POST['price']` have values that not exists in table.

Comment: Adding info to the topic.

Comment: `trim($_POST['price'])`? You're sending something with that price.

Comment: Mhh, there don't seem to be any whitespaces. But have a look at the new edit. I almost freaked out.

Comment: UTF-8, BOM - I don't know. It's not a query fault so... Happy hunting :-)

Comment: Found it, I used Unicode in the form. That -somehow- broke it. Thanks for all your time, have a nice weekend =)